# Finding intercalates within a (reduced) latin square

Tags: graph-theory, latin-square

I need confirmation on if my intuition on finding intercalates is correct, suppose we have the following reduced latin square

\begin{bmatrix}
    1  & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    2       & 4 & 1 & 3  \\
    3       & 1 & 4 & 2\\
    4       & 3 & 2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}

we know from a theorem that for a latin square of order n(even), there is at most $\frac{n^2(n-1)}{4}$ intercalates; in this case 12.

I am not sure if two 2 x 2 sub matrixes can be considered the same intercalate if they are flipped and rotated versions of each other. From the square above we get: (e.g R1 = row 1)

R1,R2
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  & 2 & |  3&4\\
    2       & 4 & |1&3 
\end{bmatrix}
R1,R3
\begin{bmatrix}
    1  & 2 & |  3&4\\
    3       & 1 & |4&2 
\end{bmatrix}
R1,R4\begin{bmatrix}
    1  & 2 & |  3&4\\
    4       & 3 & |2&1 
\end{bmatrix}
R2,R3
\begin{bmatrix}
    2  & 4 & |  1&3\\
    3      & 1 & |4&2 
\end{bmatrix}
R2,R4
\begin{bmatrix}
    2  & 4 & |  1&3\\
    4      & 3 & |2&1 
\end{bmatrix}

R3,R4
\begin{bmatrix}
    3  & 1 & |  4&2\\
    4       & 3 & |2&1 
\end{bmatrix}

And only keeping ones that are not flips and rotations of each other (I keep 1 copy). These should be the only intercalates right? So 6 of them.

\begin{bmatrix}
    1&2&|3&4&|&3&4&|&1&2&|1&2&|&2&4&\\
    2&4&|1&3&|&4&2&|&3&1&|4&3&|&3&1&
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: What is an intercalate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of these are intercalates. As defined [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.04981) (for example), we're looking for two rows $i,j$ and two columns $x,y$ such that $L_{i,x} = L_{j,y}$ and $L_{j,x} = L_{i,y}$. There are four of these in your example:

- $\{i,j\} =\{1,4\}$ and $\{x,y\} = \{1,4\}$: $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 4 \\ 4 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
- $\{i,j\} =\{2,3\}$ and $\{x,y\} = \{2,3\}$: $$\begin{bmatrix}4 & 1 \\ 1 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$
- $\{i,j\} =\{1,4\}$ and $\{x,y\} = \{2,3\}$: $$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 3 \\ 3 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$
- $\{i,j\} =\{2,3\}$ and $\{x,y\} = \{1,4\}$: $$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 3 \\ 3 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Misha, i wrote up some code to find these intercalates for me and there seems to be more than 4 sets of coordinates that produces the same 4 matrices, for instance, {i,j}={2,3} and {x,y}={3,2} -> L(2,3) = L(3,2) and L(3,3) = L(2,2) produces the second matrix. Does it not matter which of these coordinates i choose as long as only for of these matrices are found; or should there only be one set of coordinates that gives the matrix and i got the code wrong?

Comment: $\{x,y\} = \{3,2\}$ and $\{x,y\} = \{2,3\}$ are the same *set* of columns, so you should not count them twice.

Comment: oh i see, makes sense now since there was 16 sets of coordinates that the code produced